# Calculate mean of 3rd quintile for each groupby

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `df` and I want to calculate mean of the 3rd quintile for each group. The way do is to write a self defined function and to apply for each group; but there are some issues. The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(np.array(range(20))), 'B': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b']})

def func_mean_quintile(df):
    # Make sure data is in DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df['pct'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.cut(df.iloc[:,0], 5, labels=np.r_[1:6]))
    avg = df[df['pct'] == 3].iloc[:,0].mean()
    return np.full((len(df)), avg)

df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].apply(func_mean_quintile)
```

The result is `NaN` for all column `C`

I don't know where is it wrong?

Plus if you know how to make self defined function perform better, please help

Thank you

Comment: Please update your post with the expect result of your sample?

Answer (score 1):

### Proposed solution without function

You do not need a function; this should do the calc:

```
q_lo = 0.4 # start of 3d quintile
q_hi = 0.6 # end of 3d quintile

(df.groupby('B')
    .apply(lambda g:g.assign(C = g.loc[(g['A'] >= g['A'].quantile(q_lo)) & (g['A'] < g['A'].quantile(q_hi)), 'A' ].mean()))
    .reset_index(drop = True)
)
```

output:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   a   4.5
1   1   a   4.5
2   2   a   4.5
3   3   a   4.5
4   4   a   4.5
5   5   a   4.5
6   6   a   4.5
7   7   a   4.5
8   8   a   4.5
9   9   a   4.5
10  10  b   14.5
11  11  b   14.5
12  12  b   14.5
13  13  b   14.5
14  14  b   14.5
15  15  b   14.5
16  16  b   14.5
17  17  b   14.5
18  18  b   14.5
19  19  b   14.5
```

### Your original solution

Also works if you replace the line `df['C'] = ...` with

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(func_mean_quintile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.Series(np.array(range(20))), 'B':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b' ,'b']})

def func_mean_quintile(df):
# Make sure data is in DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['pct'] = pd.to_numeric(pd.cut(df.iloc[:,0], 5, labels=np.r_[1:6]))
avg = df[df['pct'] == 3].iloc[:,0].mean()
return np.full((len(df)), avg)
means = df.groupby('B').apply(func_mean_quintile)
df['C'][df["B"]=='a'] = means["a"]
df['C'][df["B"]=='b'] = means["b"]
```

This will give you the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Think its easier if you split it in two different steps. First label each datapoint with which quantile it is in. Secondly just an aggregation per quantile.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": pd.Series(np.array(range(20))),
        "b": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
    }
)
df["a_quantile"] = pd.cut(df.a, bins=4, labels=["q1", "q2", "q3", "q4"])

df_agg = df.groupby("a_quantile").agg({"a": ["mean"]})

df_agg.head()
```

With the aggregation results shown below:

```py
Out[9]: 
              a
           mean
a_quantile     
q1            2
q2            7
q3           12
q4           17
```

Comment: Thank you. My actual data consist ~hundreds of groups (by SIC) so I have to loop through all the groups